# How to set default to -j2 in Makefile?

Tags: makefile

I would like to have make option "-j2" as the default.
Can I modify Makefile for that?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [GNU Make manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/) (3.82), there is nothing I can see that allows that.

You might be able to set environment variable MAKEFLAGS (to either '`-j 2`' or perhaps '`j 2`'), but otherwise, it appears you cannot.

Comment: I agree, see also here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2151605/make-make-default-to-make-j-8

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned previously one can set the environment variable `MAKEFLAGS`. But this apparently works even inside a makefile (at least with GNU make). If you add a line

```
MAKEFLAGS=-j 2
```

at the top of the makefile this should give you the desired results. I have not tested this thoroughly and maybe it does only work with recursive invocations, but that could be easily worked around with a wrapper target.

I have used this to prevent make from printing the "Entering directory"/"Leaving directory" messages in recursive executions by setting `MAKEFLAGS=-s`.