# Error building wxWidgets using -j (jobs) option with MinGW

Tags: c++, compilation, makefile, mingw, wxwidgets

I'm compiling WxWidgets for Windows using the following command line:

```
mingw32-make -f makefile.gcc BUILD=release SHARED=1 -j6
```

The last parameter (`-j`) is used to speed up the compilation by running [multiple jobs in parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Parallel.html#Parallel), in my case making full use of my 6-core processor. A single-threaded build normally takes *very* long.

However, I get the following output when hitting Enter:

```
if not exist gcc_mswudll mkdir gcc_mswudll
if not exist ..\..\lib\gcc_dll mkdir ..\..\lib\gcc_dll
if not exist ..\..\lib\gcc_dll\mswu\wx\setup.h copy ..\..\include\wx\msw\setup.h ..\..\lib\gcc_dll\mswu\wx\setup.h
gcc -c -o gcc_mswudll\wxregex_regcomp.o  -O2 -mthreads  -DHAVE_W32API_H -DNDEBUG -I..\..\include -I..\..\lib\gcc_dll\msw
u -D__WXMSW__  -D_UNICODE   -MTgcc_mswudll\wxregex_regcomp.o -MFgcc_mswudll\wxregex_regcomp.o.d -MD -MP ../../src/regex/
regcomp.c
The system can not find the path specified.
        0 file(s) copied.
makefile.gcc:5651: recipe for target '..\..\lib\gcc_dll\mswu\wx\setup.h' failed
mingw32-make: *** [..\..\lib\gcc_dll\mswu\wx\setup.h] Error 1
mingw32-make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
In file included from ..\..\include/wx/defs.h:27:0,
                 from ../../src/regex/regcustom.h:39,
                 from ../../src/regex/regguts.h:38,
                 from ../../src/regex/regcomp.c:33:
..\..\include/wx/platform.h:183:22: fatal error: wx/setup.h: No such file or directory
 #include "wx/setup.h"
                      ^
compilation terminated.
makefile.gcc:5702: recipe for target 'gcc_mswudll\wxregex_regcomp.o' failed
mingw32-make: *** [gcc_mswudll\wxregex_regcomp.o] Error 1
```

Then, if I just repeat the same command a second time, the following output is shown:

```
if not exist ..\..\lib\gcc_dll\mswu mkdir ..\..\lib\gcc_dll\mswu
if not exist ..\..\lib\gcc_dll\mswu\wx\setup.h copy ..\..\include\wx\msw\setup.h ..\..\lib\gcc_dll\mswu\wx\setup.h
gcc -c -o gcc_mswudll\wxregex_regcomp.o  -O2 -mthreads  -DHAVE_W32API_H -DNDEBUG -I..\..\include -I..\..\lib\gcc_dll\msw
u -D__WXMSW__  -D_UNICODE   -MTgcc_mswudll\wxregex_regcomp.o -MFgcc_mswudll\wxregex_regcomp.o.d -MD -MP ../../src/regex/
regcompThe system can not find the path specified.
.c
        0 file(s) copied.
makefile.gcc:5651: recipe for target '..\..\lib\gcc_dll\mswu\wx\setup.h' failed
mingw32-make: *** [..\..\lib\gcc_dll\mswu\wx\setup.h] Error 1
mingw32-make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
In file included from ..\..\include/wx/defs.h:27:0,
                 from ../../src/regex/regcustom.h:39,
                 from ../../src/regex/regguts.h:38,
                 from ../../src/regex/regcomp.c:33:
..\..\include/wx/platform.h:183:22: fatal error: wx/setup.h: No such file or directory
 #include "wx/setup.h"
                      ^
compilation terminated.
makefile.gcc:5702: recipe for target 'gcc_mswudll\wxregex_regcomp.o' failed
mingw32-make: *** [gcc_mswudll\wxregex_regcomp.o] Error 1
```

Then... If I try a third time, the compilation finishes successfully.

**Question:** Is it ok to follow this procedure to build WxWidgets in parallel, or is there a possibility that it will lead to problems when using the compiled binaries later on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately there is indeed a bug in MSW makefiles with missing dependencies of the various libraries on `setup_h` target. It should be safe to do `make setup_h` first and then `make -jN`.

Alternatively, you could build using configure as explained in this old but still valid [post](http://wxwidgets.blogspot.com/2011/06/choosing-gcc-for-building-wxwidgets.html), then just `make -jN` works perfectly fine.