# make - remove intermediate files silently

Tags: makefile, rm, building

When building a chain rule make automatically invokes rm to remove any intermediate files at the end of the build process. Since I have about 400 intermediate files to delete that way, that floods console output badly.

Is there a way to silently rm those intermediate files, so that eighter nothing will be echoed after the build is finished oder a message like "Removing intermediate files" is echoed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could run `make -s` or build your very own version of make with this patch applied:

```
diff --git file.c file.c
index ae1c285..de3c426 100644
--- file.c
+++ file.c
@@ -410,18 +410,6 @@ remove_intermediates (int sig)
                   {
                     if (! doneany)
                       DB (DB_BASIC, (_("Removing intermediate files...\n")));
-                    if (!silent_flag)
-                      {
-                        if (! doneany)
-                          {
-                            fputs ("rm ", stdout);
-                            doneany = 1;
-                          }
-                        else
-                          putchar (' ');
-                        fputs (f->name, stdout);
-                        fflush (stdout);
-                      }
                   }
                 if (status < 0)
                   perror_with_name ("unlink: ", f->name);
```

Comment: -s is sort of a solution, but I think I can't just compile my own version because others have to be able to compile my code as well, and I dont want inconsistancies

Answer (score 3):

Expanding on the accepted answer, you can modify Make's flags from within the `Makefile` itself (as demonstrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10567890/parallel-make-set-j8-as-the-default-option/30497429#30497429)). So, for your situation, you can include this at the top of your `Makefile`:

```
MAKEFLAGS += --silent
```

The only thing to be aware of is that the `--silent` flag silences *all* Make's output. Including the "Nothing to be done" notices.

Edit:

You can also add your target as a dependency to `.SILENT`, as described at https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Special-Targets.html.

Comment: Seems like `.SILENT` only works if it is applied globally. When I use it for a single `.INTERMEDIATE` rule, the `rm` command is still printed.