# Set number of threads used by make permanently

Tags: linux, multithreading, makefile

Always when i want to compile using make command in linux I run it with -j9 to set number of threads to be used. Is there any way to set it permanently in the environment path or .bashrc file or any other way?

Comment: `alias make='make -j9'`

Comment: @JonathanWakely: Using an alias is not a good idea IMHO, considering the availability of `MAKEFLAGS`/`GNUMAKEFLAGS`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Make "make" default to "make -j 8"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2151605/make-make-default-to-make-j-8)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can set `GNUMAKEFLAGS` environment variable with extra flags to pass to GNU `make`, e.g.:

```
export GNUMAKEFLAGS=-j9
```

in your shell start-up scripts.

> **GNUMAKEFLAGS**
>
> Other flags parsed by make. You can set this in the environment or a makefile to set make command-line flags. GNU make never sets this variable itself. This variable is only needed if you’d like to set GNU make-specific flags in a POSIX-compliant makefile. This variable will be seen by GNU make and ignored by other make implementations. It’s not needed if you only use GNU make; just use MAKEFLAGS directly.

Comment: Just a note, `GNUMAKEFLAGS` is only available in GNU make 4.0 and above.  `MAKEFLAGS` is always available but note the caveat in the documentation above.