# GNU Make: how to default to parallel build?

Tags: linux, makefile, gnu-make

We have a `Makefile` where dependencies are marked correcty and it would run nicely on any number of CPU cores. We currently start the `Makefile` with

```
CPUS ?= $(shell nproc)
MAKEFLAGS += -j $(CPUS) -l $(CPUS) -s
```

and this used to work nicely in GNU Make 4.1 or lesser. However, GNU Make 4.2 or newer will emit following warning:

```
warning: -j12 forced in makefile: resetting jobserver mode.
```

(the number in the warning obviously depends on CPU cores in your system). The processing seems to result in correct output but I don't want console spam. Fortunately, this only happens for [recursive use](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Recursion.html) where a target contains rules that read `$(MAKE) ...` but this still happens often enough to spam the console.

Is it possible to *default* to `nproc` cores (or maybe `nproc` + 1 might be optimal to overlap some IO with CPU load?) if top level `make` is executed without the `-j` and `-l` flags without triggering any warnings?

The `Makefile` supports a lot of targets and I would want to default all the targets to parallel processing scaled according to the current system.

Comment: What's wrong with allowing the user to choose?  What's right with overriding the choice the user makes (even if by omission)?

Comment: If the `make` completes 12x faster by defaulting to parallel execution, wouldn't that be better default? If the user runs `make -j1` then it shouldn't use default value but run on single core only.

Comment: This is a matter of policy and role, not of defaults.  The makefile should not be taking it upon itself to make such decisions. That's not its job, and users do not expect it.  Additionally, I do not see how the specific approach presented fails to override the user's explicit choice when they make one, much less the implicit choice -- but a choice nonetheless -- they may make by omitting any `-j` option from their `make` command.

Comment: Do you think that GNU Make has implicit promise to run only on a single core unless specified otherwise? I don't assume it has made such a promise but should follow whatever rules have been specified in `Makefile`.

Comment: The `make` utility *absolutely* runs serially if not instructed otherwise.  My point is precisely that it is an abuse for a makefile to override the user's choice in that regard, as expressed by the set of options *they* choose.

Comment: So do you think that if a `make` is used to launch AI project with `make run`, it MUST NOT use multiple CPUs? I have to disagree here strongly. By definition, `make` can do *anything* that's allowed by the shell.

Comment: I think that `make` is the wrong tool for general-purpose job running, so I'm not much interested in your AI project scenario.  I also think you are improperly conflating what `make` can or should do with what makefiles can or should specify.

Comment: @MikkoRantalainen: John is *absolutely* correct. The default is, and always has been, that `make all` runs a *single* job. This is useful for debugging the build process, useful when working on a machine where yours isn't the only process running, and anyway, this is how `make` has worked for the last 50 years. If you don't like that default, you can write an alias for make, or use a system that defaults to multiple threads (e.g. [Ninja](https://ninja-build.org/)). I'd be as miffed about a Makefile forking out like I'd be about a [tarbomb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tar_(computing)#Tarbomb)

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. As long you did not call make itself inside the Makefile, you should not get this warning as I remember. I tested with gnu make 4.3

Comment: Yes, the problem surfaces when you have any commands of form `$(MAKE) ...`. I'll add that to the question.

Comment: I don't believe! If you use $(MAKE) instead of make it should also work without the warning!

Comment: I just checked and noticed that there were some calls of form `$(MAKE) -s name-of-the-target` and `$(MAKE) -C ... name-of-the target` – is it expected that adding the silent flag or using `-C` flag causes this warning if I have `MAKEFLAGS += -j ... -s` at the start of the Makefile like shown in the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able create this hack:

```
ifndef MAKEFLAGS
CPUS ?= $(shell nproc)
MAKEFLAGS += -j $(CPUS) -l $(CPUS) -s
$(info Note: running on $(CPUS) CPU cores by default, use flag -j to override.) 
endif
```

It seems to work correctly in sense if I run `make` alone, I get parallel execution on multiple CPUs and if I run `make -j2` I get execution on two cores. I don't know if this would cause additional side-effects if some other `make` flags have been used but in worst case it should default to basic GNU Make behavior of running on single core only and lose the `-s` flag in this  example.

Note that [according to the documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Testing-Flags.html) one should be able to write

```
ifeq (,$(findstring j,$(MAKEFLAGS)))
CPUS ?= $(shell nproc)
MAKEFLAGS += -j $(CPUS)
endif
```

to only adjust CPU count if not otherwise defined but in reality this doesn't work because for some yet unknown reason $(MAKEFLAGS) doesn't include the `-j` flag outside the recipes (I tested with GNU Make 4.1)!

Try Makefile like this:

```
$(warning MAKEFLAGS=$(MAKEFLAGS))
$(warning $(shell printf "[%s] " $(MAKEFLAGS)))
default:
        @printf "MAKEFLAGS in recipe: "
        @printf "[%s] " $(MAKEFLAGS)
        @echo
```

and the output of `make -j4` will be

```
Makefile:1: MAKEFLAGS=
Makefile:2: [] 
MAKEFLAGS in recipe: [-j] [--jobserver-fds=3,4]
```

Note how builtin functions such as `findstring` or `shell printf` cannot access the `-j` flag. As a result, you have to assume that if `MAKEFLAGS` has been set, the end user probably knows how he wants to set the flags and probably has set the `-j` correctly.

Comment: It appears that if the user passes other options, but no `-j`, then this will get them a serial job.  Which is right and appropriate according to me, but not what I think you intend.

Comment: Yes, that's why I call it a hack. For a better solution one would need ability to inspect if MAKEFLAGS contains a given flag and if not, then add just a single flag at a time. As far as I know, GNU Make doesn't support anything better than "is defined" or "is exactly this value" kind of logic.

Comment: Related: https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?48274 and https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=890430

Comment: You can check for individual flags, with a combination of `ifeq` (or `ifneq`) and functions like `filter` and `filter-out`.

Comment: I tried to do this but it turns out that within `ifeq` `make` lies and `-j` is not included in the `$(MAKEFLAGS)`. One could filter for `-s`/`--silent` that way but not for `-j`.